# Java swing how to set icon in menu on text position

Tags: java, html, swing

I need to put a red rectangle as a separator in JMenu. It cannot be just a separator instance, it has to be JMenuItem(JSeparator goes all the width of the menu). My issue is that when I set this rectangle as an Icon it (correctly...) moves all the menu components to the right widening whole Menu. I want it to be where text position from the above and the down elements is. 
[image]

I am trying with html but it paints nothing or just a small vertical black spot.

```
JMenuItem sep = new JMenuItem();
    sep.setText("<html><hr size=5 style='background:red;'></html>");
```

[image]

Comment: is there a closing bracket missing `<hr>...<hr/>` ? or at least close it with `<hr .../>`

Comment: Please show what is desired behavior and what is currently happening

Comment: @Sanjeev - desired behaviour is: create a seperator without using JSeperator, namly using a customized JMenuItem - what is happening is that the html-code doesn't generate the row as expected...

Comment: @MartinFrank I just added a pic to show how it looks when I use html. Closing the bracket does not change anythig.

Comment: Try to add css for <hr>  like <hr style='width :5px;' />

Comment: @nikeshjoshi yes, that would work nice, maybe you should make it longer than 5px and write an answer noit just an comment=) (tested and ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html is a small vertical spot because you haven't provided a width. By providing a width such as the below you will see your line:

```
sep.setText("<html><hr style=\"width:100px;\"></html>");
```

The fact that your line is black despite a color being provided might stem from this bug:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5059678

---

Instead of using the hr tag, you could style a component, which would give the added benefit of more flexibility with the width. With the above, your separator would always be 100 px, meaning when a large/small text based item is added to the menu it could look out of place

Would something like this work for what you need?

```
private JMenuItem createColoredSeparator(Color color){
    JMenuItem separator = new JMenuItem();
    separator.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,5));
    separator.setBackground(color);
    separator.setEnabled(false); //make the item unclickable so menu doesn't close
    return separator;
}
```

Example usage:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
menu.add(new JMenuItem("VeryLongMenuItemName"));
menu.add(createColoredSeparator(Color.RED));
menu.add(new JMenuItem("MenuItemName"));
```

Output: 
[image]

---

To make the above not fill the full width with the chosen color, you can add a Border of the default color to conceal a portion of the background with these edits in `createColoredSeparator`:

```
separator.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));   

separator.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"), 8));
```

Output:
[image]

---

**Update:** I didn't know you needed a raised border applied on top of a potential solution. You can achieve that with a [CompoundBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/CompoundBorder.html) which is covered as part of [How to use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html). This allows you to merge multiple borders together, two at a time with one being applied on the inside and the other on the outside.

Updating to the below:

```
private JMenuItem createColoredSeparator(Color color){
        JMenuItem separator = new JMenuItem();
        separator.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50)); //Increased to highlight whats happening
        //Imitate the default raised border
        Border raisedBorder = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,
                UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"),UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background").darker());
        //Merge the borders with the raised border applied outside of the border concealing part of the background
        separator.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                raisedBorder, BorderFactory.createLineBorder(UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"), 8)));
        separator.setBackground(color);
        separator.setEnabled(false); //make the item un-clickable so menu doesn't close
        return separator;
    }
```

provides the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried yout approach, but this gives me a whole jMenuItem filled with red background. What I need is a rectangle, thick line inside JMenuItem.

Comment: It looks way better, but still I have to keep the raised bevel border also on this separator menu item.

Comment: @cAMPy didn't know that you needed the raised bevel border also. I've updated my answer to include it

Answer (score 2):

You can create a customized separator by extending `JMenuItem`

```
class RedSeparator extends JMenuItem {

    public RedSeparator() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,1));
    }
}
```

You can add separator as a normal `JMenuItem`

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));
menu.add(new RedSeparator());
menu.add(new JMenuItem("Exit"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: using a `Border` is a nice idea... (methink it's a better solution than using a `<hr />` because it uses layout manager and adapts size dynamically (not fixed as in html)

Comment: Please note, that JMenuItems in this assignment already have raised bevel border and I cannot change that

Comment: @cAmpy You can always set a new border just for your separator. it will not change border for other menu items

Comment: Sanjeev this produces exactly the same result as adding JSeparator with red Background.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to add css for <hr> like <hr style='height :5px;' />
```

You can increase your height as your need.